# How to change cameras by a single touch on my phone's screen in Unity? (Android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This is a code I made but when I test it on my phone it freezes and nothing happens (same in the editor mode when I'm connected with my phone via Remote4) So What I would like to is to change cameras by just a touch on the screen any time. How should I make it?

And what's the matter when I would like to change the Camera from mainCam to topCam only when the screen is touched, and when I release the screen with my finger it changes back to mainCam from topCam?

This code goes into Update()

```
while (Input.touchCount > 0) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
                     if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && Input.GetTouch(i).tapCount == 1) {
                         if (mainCam.enabled){
                             mainCam.enabled = false;
                             topCam.enabled = true;
                         } else {
                             mainCam.enabled = true;
                             topCam.enabled = false;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: maybe your while loop is killing your app, did you try just your if, take out the while and the for loop and replace i with 0 in your first if statement, maybe your getting frozen in the app with the while loop

Comment: another thing too, i dont know about .enabled, but if you use setActive(true) and setActive(false) with just the second camera you dont have to worry about the main camera, setting the second camera to true will switch from the main camera to the second camera without doing anything to the main camera, and then setting the second camera to false will automatically switch back to the main camera

Comment: @JRowan That is true, but both cameras will stay rendering the same scene, which is expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your loops are the problem and some weird logic with the `if`s.

---

#### Touch and Hold Solution

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            topCam.enabled = true;
            mainCam.enabled = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended 
           || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)    
        {
            mainCam.enabled = true;
            topCam.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Tab Switch Solution

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
         topCam.enabled = !topCam.enabled;
         mainCam.enabled = !mainCam.enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. And what's the matter when I would like to change to the other camera by just a tap and if I tap again then it changes back?

Comment: @Gabe What do you mean?

Comment: With your code while I tap the screen and hold my finger on it, it shows the other camera. But I would like to change it with a tap (and I don't have to hold it on the screen) and change it back with another tap.

Comment: @Gabe That's easier, check the update to the code above.